# Ping IP using C# issue

Tags: c#, loops, timeout, ip, ping

I use this simple code to ping my ip address:

```
public static bool PingHost(string nameOrAddress)
{
    bool pingable = false;
    Ping pinger = new Ping();
    try
    {
        //nameOrAddress my ip, pingTImeout = 1 second
        PingReply reply = pinger.Send(nameOrAddress, pingTimeout);
        pingable = reply.Status == IPStatus.Success;
    }
    catch (PingException)
    {
        // Discard PingExceptions and return false;
    }
    return pingable;
}
```

I have a loop which executes this code every 3 seconds.

The strange point is that this loop fails one ping every 1 or 2 minutes, while, if I run the command

```
ping myIP -t
```

in the command prompt, all the ping are correct.

Why this different behavior? Maybe the code isn't the right one?

Comment: Fails how? Exception?

Comment: Have you tried expanding the pingTimeout a little and see if the failures occur less often? Also, consider to log the PingExceptions at least in DEBUG.

Comment: It doesn't go in the catch branch (I just added a log there), so, it's really probably about timeout. But why? Does it means it takes more than a second to do it???

Comment: Well if it doesn't fail with exception, what `reply.Status` is equal to?

Comment: ehm..... TimedOut...ok, thanks for the support guys, you helped me although this was a silly question probably